# Create struct from multiple arrays in a one-liner

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, vectorization

Let's say I have two arrays of the same size:

```
X = [1 2 3 4 ...]
Y = [1 2 3 4 ...]
```

But what I want is a struct:

```
S(1) =          S(2) = 
    X: 1            X: 2
    Y: 1            Y: 2
```

The obvious way to solve this is:

```
for ii = 1:length(X)
    S(ii).X = X(ii);
    S(ii).Y = Y(ii);
end
```

And you can even compress this to one line using `arrayfun`, but I am looking for a simpler one-liner. I was hoping for something along the lines of the this:

```
X = [S.X];
```

which solves the same problem but in the opposite direction.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `struct` and cells

```
S = struct('X', num2cell(X), 'Y', num2cell(Y) );
```